# Para que serve as variáveis do sistema operacional relacionadas ao Java?

Tags: java, variáveis-de-ambiente

Existem variáveis de ambiente que o Java usa para realizar certas ações, como JAVA_HOME, CLASSPATH, Path, ... A maior parte do material falando sobre essas variáveis são confusos, muitas vezes alguma informação fica de fora ou uma fonte desmente a outra, dessa maneira fica difícil saber qual o real propósito das variáveis.

Então eu queria saber para que servem essas variáveis e qual valor eu devo atribuir a elas?

Comment: O pessoal que negativa precisa lembrar de vir remover o negativo depois que a pergunta é melhorada... :) +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu irei dar exemplos no Windows, mas tudo o que muda são os caminhos das pastas.

As variáveis de ambiente no geral são usadas como forma de configurar algum aplicativo de maneira mais simples. O Java busca essas informações no sistema operacional para obter algum dado específico, como um arquivo executável.

O Java pode usar as seguintes variáveis de ambiente: JAVA_HOME, CLASSPATH, Path, JDK_HOME e JRE_HOME, JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS, JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS, _JAVA_OPTIONS e JAVA_OPTS.

Note que não é necessário ter todas essas variáveis definidas para rodar o Java, na maior parte do tempo apenas JAVA_HOME, CLASSPATH e Path são usadas.

- JAVA_HOME:

  - Aponta para a pasta base do Java (mais precisamente a pasta do JDK caso você tenha instalado ele, algo parecido com isso: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk12.0.5_24", se você não mudou a pasta do Java de lugar na hora de instalar. O mesmo vale para o JRE).
  - Esta variável é usada para mudar de forma flexível o valor das outras variáveis quando atualizarmos a versão do Java, basta mudar o valor desta variável. Também pode ser usada por outros programas para localizar a pasta do Java.
- CLASSPATH:

  - Aponta para bibliotecas de terceiros, como o próprio *JavaFX*, que já vem dentro dos arquivos do Java porém não está incluso nele.
  - O valor desta variável tem que ser algumas coisas que não estão inclusas no Java como ".;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib;". Note que "." é a pasta atual em que estamos (na hora de compilar um arquivo em Java), os ";'s" separam os caminhos e por fim "%JAVA_HOME%" está pegando o valor da variável JAVA_HOME e colocando ali.
  - Usando um exemplo com JavaFX o valor dessa variável teria o que eu citei acima e: "...;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;". O arquivo que eu especifiquei contém todos os pacotes do JavaFX comprimidos em uma arquivo .jar.
- Path:

  - Esta é uma variável muito utilizada pelo sistema.
  - Ela aponta para uma pasta que contém arquivos que executam certos comandos escritos na linha de comando, como *javac*, *java*, *jshell*, *jjs*, *jvisualvm*, entre outros.
  - O valor desta variável deve ser: "...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin". Note que esta variável pode ter outros valores já predefinidos nela.
- JDK_HOME e JRE_HOME:

  - Estas pastas simplesmente apontam para a pasta do JDK ou JRE.
  - Se você baixou o JDK, na variável JRE_HOME coloque o valor: "%JAVA_HOME%\jre". Caso contrário, coloque apenas "%JAVA_HOME%". Não defina o JDK_HOME se você instalou o JRE.
  - No JDK_HOME basta colocarmos como valor "%JAVA_HOME%".
- JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS e JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS (Java 9+):

  - Estas variáveis configuram certas coisas do java na hora de interpretar e compilar algum arquivo .java, porém existe certa diferença.
  - JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS é usado apenas pelo comando *java*.
  - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS é usado também por outros comandos como *jar* e *javac*.
  - Como são vários, recomendo que pesquise na documentação os valores destas variáveis.
- _JAVA_OPTIONS e JAVA_OPTS:

  - JAVA_OPTS deve ser ignorado e sem valor, ela não é usada pela JVM.
  - _JAVA_OPTIONS não está documentada, ela faz a mesma coisa que JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS. Esta variável está acima dos argumentos da linha de comando, e JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS está acima desta variável.

Comment: o separador de paths em windows é ponto-e-vírgula `;` mas em linux e mac-os é dois-pontos `:`

Comment: Legal que esclareceu a quais variáveis estava se referindo, mas o lugar desse esclarecimento é na pergunta e não na área de respostas.

Comment: você não explicou o essencial, sobre variáveis de ambiente, elas servem para configurações iniciais de execução da jvm, são informações que o java busca do sistema operacional, isso não serve apenas para as variáveis default que você citou, mas também para variáveis personalizadas, para tuas aplicações poderem rodar de forma diferente dependendo do ambiente, dependendo do computador.

Comment: Não são variáveis de ambiente do Java; são variáveis de ambiente do sistema operacional que são relacionadas ao Java. Java tem outras variáveis de ambiente, obtidas com `System.getProperty()` user.dir, os.name, line.separator... por isso a pergunta ganhou negativos (corretamente).